# How to change the page/plot two figures

Tags: matplotlib, figures

I am developing a tool that should produce 3 plots. Two of those are related and therefor I have created them using the the pyplot.subplot. The third one needs more space, and I would like to create it on a single chart. 
[image: What for are the arrows??]

It is clear to me, that I could plot two figures. But I would like to know how to get them showed in this same window, So that they can be accessed with these arrows.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the positions and dimensions with subplots_adjust : http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust